# How to fill out a web form from excel file and get the resulting page source

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use this code on the below link, with the same concept (transfer the data from excel) and I face many errors.

I need to change the code to match the entries.

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSek4lvyKCkjeKHJwRRSUdsNb4WCIohFNlog7YjeWVzmEr3DQQ/viewform

```
from selenium import webdriver
import sys
import time
import os
import pyautogui
import webbrowser
import openpyxl
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

chrome_path =r"C:/Users/asous/Desktop/New folder1/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSek4lvyKCkjeKHJwRRSUdsNb4WCIohFNlog7YjeWVzmEr3DQQ/viewform")

def sendvalues(driver):

    wb = load_workbook('C:/Users/asous/Desktop/New folder1/afeef.xlsx')
    ws = wb.active

    firstname = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
    lastname = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
    firstn=ws.cell(row=x, column=1).value
    lastn=ws.cell(row=x, column=2).value
    firstname.send_keys(firstn)
    lastname.send_keys(lastn)
    table(driver)

def table(driver):
    #rut = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="rut"]""")
    #dv = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="wrapper"]/form/table[1]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input""")
    #nombre = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="wrapper"]/form/table[1]/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/input""")
    coma = ","
    wb = load_workbook('C:/Users/asous/Desktop/New folder1/afeef.xlsx')
    ws = wb.active
    rutvalue=  ws.cell(row=x, column=1).value
    table_elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class = 'grilla']")))

    for table_element in table_elements:
        for row in table_element.find_elements_by_xpath(".//tr"):
            text_file = open("Output2.txt", "a")
            text_file.write(str(rutvalue)+str(coma)+str(row.text)+'\n')
            text_file.close()
            rut.clear()
            dv.clear()
            nombre.clear()

sendvalues(driver)
for x in range(1,1000):
   sendvalues(driver)
```

one of the issues is the web opened without any action (fil the data), the other mention below

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/asous/PycharmProjects/project_traning/Web automation/Web Aut 2.py", line 82, in 
sendvalues(driver)
File "C:/Users/asous/PycharmProjects/project_traning/Web automation/Web Aut 2.py", line 56, in sendvalues
firstn=ws.cell(row=x, column=1).value
NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add your error messages

Comment: Done, i edit the code and add the errors, the concept from the code I need to pass the data from my excel file to fill the filed in the web .

Comment: what isn't working for you? Are you able to log in, etc?